# Android xmpp ssl library problem

Tags: java, android, xmpp

i am new to android. i connected my server to my application. I can connect to server. but i couldn't login into server. last week i can access my server in my application.

host is 66.203.93.247
post is 5222
service is sayagle

```
ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(host,Integer.parseInt(port), service);
XmppConn = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
```

when i login into server `XmppConn.login(username+"@"+service, password);`

I got this error

---

```
java.io.IOException: Read error: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
[10:51:28 AM] saravanan: W/System.err( 2499): java.io.IOException: Read error: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
W/System.err( 2499):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.nativeread(Native Method)
W/System.err( 2499):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.access$300(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:55)
W/System.err( 2499):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:524)
W/System.err( 2499):    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:438)
W/System.err( 2499):    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:311)
W/System.err( 2499):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.peek(KXmlParser.java:876)
W/System.err( 2499):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.peekType(KXmlParser.java:557)
W/System.err( 2499):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextImpl(KXmlParser.java:305)
W/System.err( 2499):    at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:1330)
W/System.err( 2499):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:368)
W/System.err( 2499):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:44)
W/System.err( 2499):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:76)
```

---

I got IllegalStateException also.

could you please anyone help to me?

Comment: Thanks unbeli. could you please help to me for solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a known bug in asmack. Try to build the latest version from https://github.com/rtreffer/asmack